# How to run a .cmd file from VBA

Tags: vba, solidworks

I am writing a macro for a Solidworks PDM Task.
I have manage to write into the script in the Task, that it should start a specified macro. This works.

In the macro I would like to open a PcSchematic file (.pro) and the run a .cmd file, which will ask PcSchematic to convert the file into a PDF. And then close the program.

I am novice in VBA - I have found and edited this macro, which opens PcSchematic, but not the file and I don't know how to proceed.

```
Sub Auto_Open()
Dim x As Variant
Dim Path As String

' Set the Path variable equal to the path of your program's installation
Path = "C:\Pcselcad\Pcselcad.exe"

x = Shell(Path, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Right now we use a Dispatch to do the trick, with a Shell execute:
[image]

Where the commandline says: `C:\Pcselcad\Pcselcad.exe "%PathToSelectedFile%" C:\ODIN\administration\Dispatch\SaveAsPDF.cmd`

This method is working, but it is not closing down the PcSchematics when it is done. And I would like to start it with a task, which gives me some other benefits, this is why I want to do it with a macro.

Comment: Did you try `Path = "C:\Pcselcad\Pcselcad.exe ""%PathToSelectedFile%"" C:\ODIN\administration\Dispatch\SaveAsPDF.cmd"` where you replace `%PathToSelectedFile%` with the path to your file?

Comment: Sub Auto_Open()
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim Path As String

    ' Set the Path variable equal to the path of your program's installation
    Path = """C:\Pcselcad\Pcselcad.exe"" ""C:\ODIN\project\16xxx\16368 ODIN Engineering Slagelse Test af Solidworks og PDM\07 PCS\16368.01.pro"" ""C:\ODIN\administration\Dispatch\SaveAsPDF.cmd"""

    x = Shell(Path, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub This works to open program and file and run .cmd which starts generating the pdf. But This should run on a new file each time %PathToSelectedFile% and I can't find how to close the program afterwards.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments it gets unreadable. Instead [edit] your question and add it there. If it needs to run on a new file you need to put a new file name each time (use a variable and concatenate it with `&` to your string). Note that VBA cannot know when your script is finished therefore it cannot close it (unless your script as an option switch to close itself after finishing).